# Adding a new line when checking a checkbox

Tags: c#

When I click on a checkbox I want the next checkbox information to be displayed on a new line, I know how to do this with "\r\n" however when unchecking the box and rechecking the box, it adds a new line above the text moving the original text down by 1 line. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUFWG.jpg

I've tried "\r\n" and Environment.NewLine

```
        private void chkHamburger_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (chkHamburger.Checked == true)
            {
                txtHamburger.Enabled = true;
                txtHamburger.Text = "";
                txtHamburger.Focus();
                txtOrder.Text += ("Hamburger");
            }
            else
            {
                txtHamburger.Enabled = false;
                txtHamburger.Text = "0";
            }
            if (chkHamburger.Checked == false)
            {
                txtOrder.Text = txtOrder.Text.Replace("Hamburger", "");
            }
        }

        private void chkCheeseBurger_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkCheeseBurger.Checked == true)
            {
                txtCheeseBurger.Enabled = true;
                txtCheeseBurger.Text = "";
                txtCheeseBurger.Focus();
                txtOrder.Text += ("Cheese Burger");
            }
            else
            {
                txtCheeseBurger.Enabled = false;
                txtCheeseBurger.Text = "0";
            }
            if (chkCheeseBurger.Checked == false)
            {
                txtOrder.Text = txtOrder.Text.Replace("Cheese Burger", "");
            }

        }
```

I want the text of a checkbox to be displayed on a new line but when rechecking the box a whitespace should not appear above it.

Comment: It seems like it might be easier to just use a `ListBox`.

Comment: @Steve, sorted that one. Nothing to do with the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a `List<string>` where you add or remove your orders. Then it is easy to rebuild the txtOrder data with a single line of code using string.Join

```
List<string> orders = new List<string>();
private void chkHamburger_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtHamburger.Enabled = chkHamburger.Checked;
    if (chkHamburger.Checked)
    {
        txtHamburger.Text = "";
        txtHamburger.Focus();
        orders.Add("Hamburger");
    }
    else
    {
        txtHamburger.Text = "0";
        orders.Remove("Hamburger");
    }
    UpdateOrders();
}
private void chkCheeseBurger_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtCheeseBurger.Enabled = chkCheeseBurger.Checked;
    if (chkCheeseBurger.Checked)
    {
        txtCheeseBurger.Text = "";
        txtCheeseBurger.Focus();
        orders.Add("Cheese Burger");
    }
    else
    {
        txtCheeseBurger.Text = "0";
        orders.Remove("Cheese Burger");
    }
    UpdateOrders();
}

private void UpdateOrders()
{
    txtOrders.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, orders);
}
```

Comment: I would expect your final version would not use a list of strings but instead an object that include price and quantity etc.  then for example if orders is a list of these thing your text could be set with `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, orders.Select(o => o.Quantity.ToString()+" "+o.Description));`

Comment: Yes, of course that's possible and preferable, but then I would change from a TextBox to a DataGridView otherwise the result is pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to have a routine that builds the contents of the text independent of what just happened -- this you could use join or a loop to create the text contents.

Make this a function and call it when the check boxes change.  The function loops over all your items and adds them to the output with the formatting and totals etc.